# How do you conditionally disable a form input in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I would like to disable the validated input if an item meets a certain criteria. In this case if a product has a promotion.

Ideally I would like to do something like this:

```
<ValidatedInput
  className='product-dropdown'
  onChange={this.onProductChange.bind(this)}
  defaultValue={example.product_id}
  componentClass='select'
  name='product_id'
  placeholder='select'
  disabled={isDisabledInput}
 >

isDisabledInput {
  if(example.has_a_promotion) {
     return true
  }
}
```

I am using react-bootstrap-validation.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with react `per-say.

I have changed `example` to use the components `state` this will mean the `ValidatedInput` will re-render whenever the state is changed. This might not actually be necessary if example.has_a_promotion is correct when the component is rendered. So please change accordingly.

`disabled` is actually just a property that is passed down to the `ValidatedInput` component. Which means its value is just like any other js that is run when its wrapped with `{}`... so a simple if statement will do the trick.

```
 render(){
  return(    
     <ValidatedInput
       className='product-dropdown'
       onChange={this.onProductChange.bind(this)}
       defaultValue={example.product_id}
       componentClass='select'
       name='product_id'
       placeholder='select'
       disabled={this.state.example.has_a_promotion === true ? true : false}
      />
   );
 }
```

Comment: You can even simplify it further `disabled={this.state.example.has_a_promotion}`.

Comment: Assuming it has a value... I wasn't sure what this might be set to... but yep :D I kind of thought I would be rather obvious to the point.

Comment: disabled = {false} will also disable the field.

Comment: I'm not really sure why you're putting conditional logic around a boolean to return true if it's true and false if it's false. The only possible reason I can think of is if `has_a_promotion` isn't necessarily a boolean and you want to ensure a strict boolean type. If so: `!!has_a_promotion` is neater.

Comment: Purely for illustrative purposes. If somebody doesn't already understand that `disabled={isDisabledInput}` accepts a boolean... then it locally suggests they will/would need a clear example.